# Multi touch operations using monkeyrunner

Tags: android, jython, adb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, monkeyrunner

Is there any way to use multitouch in monkeyrunner. I didn't find any key events for touching on coordinates of screen simultaneously. I want to touch both wifi and Bluetooth button simultaneously.
Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

There is no key events for touching simultaneously. But you can use getevent to get the operation data.
Then restore the operation.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how getevent would be implemented to capture/restore the operation? I've seen this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220463/how-i-can-link-android-activity-change-with-adb-getevent-command) but am unsure of how the ADB call can be used to implement simultaneous touches.